# CSS: horizontal align two inner divs vertically

Tags: html, css, navbar

I got a major problem, that I don't seem to solve. I'm trying to get a logo (text) and a navbar (text) to align horizontally, but when that's completed, it seems like it doesn't align so, that the navbar stays at the same line as the logo.

Can anyone help me?

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#logo {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-links {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#navbar-links ul {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
#navbar-links li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-links li a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:active {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="Logo">
    <h1>NUMBERS</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposition the `#navbar-links` before `#Logo`:

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#logo {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-links {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
#navbar-links ul {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
#navbar-links li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-links li a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:hover {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar-links li a:active {
  color: #c3c3c3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Logo">
    <h1>NUMBERS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float for the layout, then you can simply use the vertical-align property.

```
#logo,
#navbar-links {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -.25em // If you are not compressing html
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%; //adjust to taste.
}

#navbar-links {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is very simple one ...

you had id in the HTML  as "Logo" and in css it is "logo".
So because of the case sensitivity, browser is not connecting the CSS to HTML.

```
#Logo { //Its case sensitive so not "logo"
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

You can refer this link [for the code correction](http://jsfiddle.net/DDSridhar/f0eee124/18/)